# Inject resource as primitive type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, primitive, boxing

I'm currently injecting a resource as boolean like this:

```
@Resource(name = "java:global/myBooleanValue")
String strValue;
boolean boolValue = Boolean.parseBoolean( strValue );
```

Is there a way to inject the resource directly as boolean using the `type` parameter?
`@Resource(name = ..., type = Boolean.class)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Annotate setter instead of the field and do some conversion there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public class Test {
    private boolean boolValue;

    @Resource(name = "java:global/myBooleanValue")
    private void setBoolValue(String: strVal) {
         boolValue = Boolean.parseBoolean(strVal);
    }
}
```